# function elm(obj){ return document.getElementById(obj); }

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am using the following function to simplify the use of **getElementById**:

```
function elm(obj){
return document.getElementById(obj);
}
//Usage: elm("id").innerHTML = "hello";
```

**My Questions:**

- Is it recommended to use it?
- Are there better ways of achieving this?

Comment: That's fine, but I suggest renaming the parameter to `id` (or `elmId` or something), because `obj` implies that the function is expecting an object rather than an id string.

Comment: @SLaks: Use jQuery to simplify `document.getElementById`? Massive overkill.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: No; use jQuery to simplfiy the rest of his code too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your function.

The only problem is that if you are like one of the many people that use a Javascript framework to help with the really annoying stuff like events or AJAX then it is probably more idiomatic to instead use whatever function your library already provides to select DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use that. If you are using jQuery then easier way exist, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yourElementId").html(); // or any other function you want instead of html
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I am anti-JQuery right now, because I just started learning JavaScript few years ago (and I think that if I start using JQuery, It will hurt me more than help)

Comment: @ogps92 You just started learning JavaScript... a few years ago... ? Understanding the fundamentals of JavaScript takes a few months tops - just get a good book and watch the Crockford lectures...

Comment: well, for me it takes years hehehe, :(

Comment: @ogps92 it can be a crutch for beginners, but once you have the fundamentals down (which it sounds like you do), jQuery will only enhance your productivity. You don't write your own web server in c, right?